# Best way to structure a table with several columns

Tags: tables, comparison, analytics

I have the following table that needs to be structured in a much more appealing manner -

[image]

I've been breaking my head into how to structure this better to fit in a desktop screen and also make the most sense for the user.

Points to be noted are -

1. Office 2 is the parent object for Office 3 & 4. So basically, if Office 2 is Europe, Office 3 & 4 will be Netherlands and Belgium respectively and so on.
2. S1 -> S16 are a set of quality standards that each office must adhere to when delivering a product.
3. In analytics, 1/10 indicates the number of standards that are being met per unit that is sold. If 1/10 -> that means that only 1/10 products met S1.
4. There are 12-15 sub-offices per office

How can I structure this table to be more visually appealing and also give the user the data that they want?

Answer (score 1):

You can invert the rows and columns like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcVxq4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

And put a filter for the user to filter the standards.

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning but we generally have around 15 sub offices as well :/

Comment: I've also updated the question.

Comment: In this case, I would keep the table the way you proposed and put a filter in the "offices" column, so the user could select which office would like to see the standards